# MS Access Report Popup

Tags: ms-access

I have created a report so that when it opens it is a popup form however it looks like this and has too much white space https://gyazo.com/2026b211e7d600fd80a967b27edd1a1d

I tried in design view to make it the size i wanted and yet the white space is still visible https://gyazo.com/7f57630591c9627a7200fadd3c16bd8d

I thought if i put auto resize on no then this would not happen but everything i have tried to so far doesnt't work. I have a few popup forms that meet the size i want and i can adjust it quite freely but the same isnt happening for reports. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This looks like it should be a form, not a report. -- Is this Report view or Print preview?

Comment: Its a report as im taking it from a query so i can find customers via customerID and its in report view

Answer (score 0):

Check Layout view and make sure your objects aren't extending past the margins. It seems really silly, but I struggled with this the other week.

Also, as mentioned, this should be a form. You can still use a query as a recordsource on a form.